# Python: Add new value to previous value from a leapmotion controller

Tags: python

I'm sending position data from a leap motion controller and setting that position data in a 3d software to move an object. But I need the object to remember its previous position and add it to the data it is fed by the leap.

So if the first position value is 206.901, the 2nd position will be previous position plus 196.799 and so on

This is the udp position data received inside of my 3dsoftware from the leap controller:

```
received message: 206.901992798
received message: 196.799606323
received message: 218.851989746
received message: 206.74659729
received message: 217.411819458
```

this is the 3d software code for setting the position of the object :

```
while(True):
    try:

        rightswipe_x = hou.session.sock.recv(1024) 
        rightswipe_x = float(rightswipe_x) #string to float

        print "received message:", rightswipe_x

        # x coordinate 

        effector = hou.node('/obj/geo1/transform1') # get object from scene 

        x2 = effector.parm('tx') # get value of current x position of effector


        x2.set(rightswipe_x/500)  #set tx parameter to value 

        x2 = effector.evalParm('tx') # re-evaluate parameter for x position  
        print 'x position:',x2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely need a variable that will be incremented.
It is difficult to give you an example without seeing your code, but it will be something like this:

```
position = 0
for i in range (*whatever the number of your positions will be*):
    position += (*whatever your input is*)
print(position)
```

Once you exit this loop, all the positions will be summed. 
I hope it helps

Give us some more info to help you.

Comment: so maybe i'm being really thick but it's a live stream of numbers from the leap sensor that i'm sending out so i don't have a range do i?

import socket

UDP_IP = 'localhost' UDP_PORT = 7864

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT)) while True:
rightswipe_x, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

#print "received message:", rightswipe_x
rightswipe_x = float(rightswipe_x) #string to float
position = rightswipe_x


#for i in range(0,position):
#   print i
#   position = position + i
#   print position

Answer (score 0):

so maybe i'm being really thick but it's a live stream of numbers from the leap sensor that i'm sending out so i don't have a range do i?

import socket

UDP_IP = 'localhost'
UDP_PORT = 7864

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
while True:
    rightswipe_x, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

```
#print "received message:", rightswipe_x
rightswipe_x = float(rightswipe_x) #string to float
position = rightswipe_x


#for i in range(0,position):
#   print i
#   position = position + i
#   print position
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your addition should happen after some action. In the code you provided you have a while-loop action.

So, while true:

```
rightswipe_x = float(rightswipe_x) #string to float
position += rightswipe_x
```

If I am reading your code right: instead of incrementing the "position" in our case now :) you just keep reassigning it.

Instead, change it to +=, which can be translated to

```
position = position + rightswipe_x
```

I hope it will work.

Also, the code you posted did not display right, so I am not sure if your indentation is right. Make sure, it is formated like this:

```
while True:
   rightswipe_x, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

   #print "received message:", rightswipe_x
   rightswipe_x = float(rightswipe_x) #string to float
   position = rightswipe_x

return position
```